# TextView not displaying Result

Tags: android, barcode, zxing, barcode-scanner

I'm doing this app where it scans the barcode and display the result. Currently the `TexView` is not displaying anything after scaning the barcode can you guys  help me?

Here's the `MainActivity.java`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scrollable_tabs);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFrag(new OneFragment(), "ONE");
        adapter.addFrag(new TwoFragment(), "TWO");
        adapter.addFrag(new ThreeFragment(), "THREE");
        adapter.addFrag(new FourFragment(), "FOUR");
        adapter.addFrag(new FiveFragment(), "FIVE");
        adapter.addFrag(new SixFragment(), "SIX");
        adapter.addFrag(new SevenFragment(), "SEVEN");
        adapter.addFrag(new EightFragment(), "EIGHT");
        adapter.addFrag(new NineFragment(), "NINE");
        adapter.addFrag(new TenFragment(), "TEN");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the scanner code

```
public class OneFragment extends Fragment{
    public OneFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    Button scan_btn;
    TextView barcode;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle   savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
        scan_btn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.scan_button);
        //initialize the textViews
        barcode = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.barcodeResult);
        final Activity activity = getActivity();
        scan_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(activity);
                integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.PRODUCT_CODE_TYPES);
                integrator.setPrompt("Scan");
                integrator.setCameraId(0);
                integrator.setBeepEnabled(false);
                integrator.setBarcodeImageEnabled(true);
                integrator.initiateScan();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (result != null) {
            barcode.setText(result.getContents());
        }else {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getContext(),"No scan data received!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
    }
}
```

And the xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <Button android:id="@+id/scan_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="scan" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/barcodeResult"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Start scanning by pressing the FAB!"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: what the textView display, is it gives yo an error ?

Comment: maybe the activity result should be on the activity instead the fragment?

Comment: Activity or Fragment make no sence the function must works with boths

Comment: nope no error just giving a null i think

Comment: nope no error just giving a null i think

Comment: @dasser could you elaborate?

Comment: can you upload the app to let me trace it ?

Comment: I was just meaning  that if you use a fragment or an activity your reslut must go the right way

Comment: hmmm then what it seems the problem  cant seem to figure it out

Comment: the problem is within the method you are getting the result with because as you said it gives you null, so you can trace it with debugging if you want

Comment: Please make your question shorter. We won't debug the problem you've there. Please be more specific about your problem to get faster response.

Comment: i debugged the program and the onactivityresult is not being called out

Comment: @DasserBasyouni heres a link https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B63ARvB_T0AOS3FkWjZ6VjIzQkE

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `OnActivityResult` in your `Activity` is calling `super.OnActivityResult()`. That should ensure it's called on the `Fragment` as well.

or..

try this wrapper class: instead of `IntentIntegrator`

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegrator;

public final class FragmentIntentIntegrator extends IntentIntegrator {

    private final Fragment fragment;

    public FragmentIntentIntegrator(Fragment fragment) {
        super(fragment.getActivity());
        this.fragment = fragment;
    }

    @Override
    protected void startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int code) {
        fragment.startActivityForResult(intent, code);
    }
}
```

it ensures that `fragment` `onactivityresult` is called..

call it in your OneFragment like;

```
FragmentIntentIntegrator integrator = new FragmentIntentIntegrator (this);
```

or...

see this http://androide-examples.blogspot.com/2013/11/zxing-onactivityresult-called-only-in.html

it shows the detail implementation

Comment: for the super.onactivityresult how do you put it in the code. sorry im new to java and android

Answer (score 0):

When coming back from another activity the system might try to restore the view state, actually overwriting what you just wrote.

Save your result into a member and try overriding onViewStateRestored in your fragment

```
    @Override
    public void onViewStateRestored(Bundle savedInstanceState){
     super.onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState);
     if( barcode != null ){
         barcode.setText(mResult);
     }
    }
```

Comment: put it in my fragment code? sorry could you provide a sample cos im new to these learning as hard as i can

Comment: If your onActivityResult is not being called then that is the first issue you have to look at. My code just prevents the fragment views (your textviews) to be reset to previous values but if onActivityResult isn't called my code won't do anything special.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry fo being late but that's because the so much errors I got to compile you project, also it is easier for you to upload it at Github

Anyway, the way you are using the scanner is not entering the `onActivityResult()` method at all so I have re-created it as [MainActivity class of the sample library](https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/example/zxing/MainActivity.java) 
also with you customization for sure

Here is your code, I have tested it and it surely works, you just need to copy and paste it

```
package info.androidhive.materialtabs.fragments;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegrator;
import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentResult;

import info.androidhive.materialtabs.R;


public class OneFragment extends Fragment{
public OneFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

private String toast;
Button scan_btn;
TextView barcode;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
    scan_btn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.scan_button);
    barcode = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.barcodeResult);
    scan_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            scanFromFragment();
        }
    });
    return view;
}

public void scanFromFragment() {
    IntentIntegrator.forSupportFragment(this)
            .setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.PRODUCT_CODE_TYPES)
            .setPrompt("Scan")
            .setCameraId(0)
            .setBeepEnabled(false)
            .setBarcodeImageEnabled(true)
            .initiateScan();
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(result != null) {
        if(result.getContents() == null) {
            toast = "Cancelled from fragment";
        } else {
            barcode.setText(result.getContents());
            toast = "Scanned from fragment: " + result.getContents();
        }

        // At this point we may or may not have a reference to the activity
        displayToast();
    }
}

private void displayToast() {
    if(getActivity() != null && toast != null) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), toast, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        toast = null;
    }
}
}
```

Also add to your `barcodeResult` in `fragment_one` layout `android:layout_below="@+id/scan_button"` because it is right behind the scan button

Comment: @Jason Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please note that the preferred way of saying 'thanks' around here is by
up-voting good questions and helpful answers (once you have enough
reputation to do so), and by accepting the most helpful answer to any
question you ask (which also gives you a small boost to your
reputation).
Please see the [About] page and also [How do I ask questions
here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)